# How to create a Arduino socket server to receive messages

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, networking

From linux I can send a socket message using netcat

```
echo "Hello" | nc 88.109.110.161 100
```

But I don't know how to setup the socket server for listening incoming messages using the ethernet shield.

What I have so far is one from a lot of examples I tried but still not showing anything

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

EthernetServer server(1000);

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  Serial.begin(9600);
// Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
  }

  // start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
 EthernetClient client = server.available();
 if (client) {
   Serial.println("Client");
   // an http request ends with a blank line
   boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
   while (client.connected()) {
     while(client.available()) {
       char c = client.read();
       // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
       // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
       // so you can send a reply
       if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {

// Here is where the POST data is.  
         while(client.available())
         {
            Serial.write(client.read());
            //Serial.println(c);
         }
         Serial.println();

         Serial.println("Sending response");
         // send a standard http response header
         //client.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
         //client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
         //client.println();
         client.println("OK");
         client.stop();
       }
       else if (c == '\n') {
         // you're starting a new line
         currentLineIsBlank = true;
       }
       else if (c != '\r') {
         // you've gotten a character on the current line
         currentLineIsBlank = false;
       }
     }
   }
   Serial.println("Disconnected");
 }
}
```

Comment: have you confirmed that your ethernet shield is functional?

Comment: see the ChatServer example

Comment: Where is your ```Ethernet.begin```? Surely you still need one of those. have a look at the ```setup()``` in the docs here: [EthernetServer Example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetServer)

Comment: the shield is fully functional, I'm able to receive http post requests, that's how I figure it out, but I still needing the socket server, just to receive raw messaages

Comment: I updated the code, that's how actually receives http requests

Comment: What do you mean by "needing the socket server" and "to get the raw request"? 
I would have thought that your are already doing that. After all, your loop is reading the incoming socket data character by character and assembling it into a string. You are dealing with the low level http protocol (in the example above) by checking the new lines. How much lower do you "need" to go?

Comment: Maybe a typo but you send your message to Port 100 and the Arduino is listening to Port 1000 ;)

Answer (score -1):

I am learning to use the arduino library about sockets and I spent an hour detecting why your example was not working for me, I ended up noticing that you have one line wrong

```
if (c = '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
```

should be:

```
{ if (c != '\n' && !currentLineIsBlank) {
```

And you still have an error you are missing a return character because you are not printing it in the second loop.

Anyway thanks for your contributions.

Comment: there is `==` and that is right